# German email resource file

Tags: email, resources, docusignapi

some colleagues are using DocuSign in german language and theay would like to change the text of e-mails the signer receives.

I would like to know if the resource file in German language exists and if yes, how I could get it.
We would like to change a bit the e-mail that user gets from DocuSign in DocuSign_EmailResources.xml

I this file https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign%20Signing%20Resource%20File%20Information.pdf I found how to set up the language. Does it mean, that I have to rewrite the whole text to German by myself?

Could you please help with that question?

Best Regards, Irina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irina,

You only need to change the email test for the one you want to change. It is a Delta change, not a all or nothing. You can export only the english version master, and then change the language node for the email you wish to change and make the language edits and upload back and test.

Your account manager will need to enable the multiple language support, so please contact them.